# React Native Using ref from a hook

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to optimize my code with hooks. I am thinking to move all bottom sheet refs into a useBottomSheet hook so I can share those refs and be able to manipulate the bottom sheet from any components that import the refs, or callbacks that use those refs. SO I have this:

```
export const useBottomSheet = () => {
  const searchModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);
  const handleOpenFilters = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('GO');
    searchModalRef.current?.snapToIndex(0);
  }, []);
```

In my screen I have

```
const SearchScreen = () => {
  const { searchModalRef } = useBottomSheet();
  return (
    <>
      <Button onPress={() => searchModalRef.current?.snapToIndex(0)} title="PRESS" />
      <BottomSheet
        ref={searchModalRef}
        ...
      />
```

When I press the button, the BottomSheet moves. But when I import `const { handleOpenFilters } = useBottomSheet();` in another component and use it, I can see it prints "GO" in the console, but the bottomsheet doesn't move. How come?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to return the values you destructure when you call the hook!

```js
export const useBottomSheet = () => {
  const searchModalRef = useRef<BottomSheetModal>(null);
  const handleOpenFilters = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('GO');
    return searchModalRef.current?.snapToIndex(0);
  }, []);
// add this:
return { searchModalRef, handleOpenFilters }
}
```

Comment: I did. I just saved us all time not adding it to my question. It would not print "Go" in the console if I did not return `handleOpenFilters`.

Comment: try to `return searchModalRef.current?.snapToIndex(0)`